# Compiler error trying to parse one integer in string using boost::spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, compiler-errors, boost-spirit

I am trying to parse a string that contains some special word and integer next to it.
Let special word be "HHH". It is needed to skip data before it and parse data after. Here is my try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main ()
{
    std::string input = "asd eee rrr HHH 456";
    std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();
    int result;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
            strbegin, input.end(),
            (*(qi::char_ - qi::lit("HHH")) >> qi::lit("HHH") >> qi::int_),
            qi::space,                  
            result);                               

    std::cout << ok << std::endl;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
main.cpp:14:   instantiated from here                                                                                                                                                                
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:454: error: no matching function for call to mpl_::void_::void_(int)                                                            
/usr/include/boost/mpl/void.hpp:29: note: candidates are: mpl_::void_::void_()                                                                                                                       
/usr/include/boost/mpl/void.hpp:29: note:                 mpl_::void_::void_(const mpl_::void_&)                                                                                                     
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp: In static member function static bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::extract_int<T, Radix, 1u, -0x00000000000000001, Accumulator, Accumulate>::parse_main(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, Accumulator = boost::spirit::qi::detail::positive_accumulator<10u>, bool Accumulate = false]:                                                   
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:501:   instantiated from static bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::extract_int<T, Radix, 1u, -0x00000000000000001, Accumulator, Accumulate>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, Accumulator = boost::spirit::qi::detail::positive_accumulator<10u>, bool Accumulate = false]                                                           
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/numeric_utils.hpp:108:   instantiated from static bool boost::spirit::qi::extract_int<T, Radix, MinDigits, MaxDigits>::call(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, unsigned int MinDigits = 1u, int MaxDigits = -0x00000000000000001]                                                                                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/int.hpp:98:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<T, Radix, MinDigits, MaxDigits>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, unsigned int MinDigits = 1u, int MaxDigits = -0x00000000000000001]                                                                                                                            
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/fail_function.hpp:38:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<Iterator, Context, Skipper>::operator()(const Component&, Attribute&) const [with Component = boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, Attribute = mpl_::void_, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >]                                                                                                                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/algorithm/any_if.hpp:171:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::detail::any_if(const First1&, const First2&, const Last&, F&, mpl_::false_) [with Pred = boost::spirit::traits::attribute_not_unused<const boost::fusion::unused_type, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, First1 = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> >, Last = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::nil>, First2 = boost::fusion::vector_iterator<boost::fusion::vector1<int&>, 1>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, const boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >]                                                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/algorithm/any_if.hpp:171:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::detail::any_if(const First1&, const First2&, const Last&, F&, mpl_::false_) [with Pred = boost::spirit::traits::attribute_not_unused<const boost::fusion::unused_type, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, First1 = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > >, Last = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::nil>, First2 = boost::fusion::vector_iterator<boost::fusion::vector1<int&>, 1>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, const boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >]                                                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/algorithm/any_if.hpp:171:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::detail::any_if(const First1&, const First2&, const Last&, F&, mpl_::false_) [with Pred = boost::spirit::traits::attribute_not_unused<const boost::fusion::unused_type, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, First1 = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, Last = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::nil>, First2 = boost::fusion::vector_iterator<boost::fusion::vector1<int&>, 0>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, const boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >]                       
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/algorithm/any_if.hpp:186:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::any_if(const Sequence1&, Sequence2&, F, Pred) [with Pred = boost::spirit::traits::attribute_not_unused<const boost::fusion::unused_type, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, Sequence1 = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > >, Sequence2 = boost::fusion::vector1<int&>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, const boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >]                                                                                                                                                                                      
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/sequence_base.hpp:81:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::sequence_base<Derived, Elements>::parse_impl(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&, mpl_::false_) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = int, Derived = boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, Elements = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > >]                      
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/sequence_base.hpp:115:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::sequence_base<Derived, Elements>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_t, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::dereference, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::minus, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, const boost::proto::utility::literal<const char (&)[4], boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain>&>, 2l>&>, 1l>&, const boost::proto::utility::literal<const char (&)[4], boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain>&>, 2l>&, const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_>&>, 2l>, Skipper = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, Attr = int]::skipper_type, Attribute = int, Derived = boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, Elements = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[4], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> > >]                                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:114:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_t, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::dereference, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::minus, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, const boost::proto::utility::literal<const char (&)[4], boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain>&>, 2l>&>, 1l>&, const boost::proto::utility::literal<const char (&)[4], boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain>&>, 2l>&, const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_>&>, 2l>, Skipper = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, Attr = int]                                                 
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:132:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::dereference, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::minus, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, const boost::proto::utility::literal<const char (&)[4], boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain>&>, 2l>&>, 1l>&, const boost::proto::utility::literal<const char (&)[4], boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain>&>, 2l>&, const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_>&>, 2l>, Skipper = boost::spirit::standard::space_type, Attr = int]                                           
main.cpp:14:   instantiated from here                                                                                                                                                                
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:454: error: no matching function for call to mpl_::void_::void_(int)                                                            
/usr/include/boost/mpl/void.hpp:29: note: candidates are: mpl_::void_::void_()                                                                                                                       
/usr/include/boost/mpl/void.hpp:29: note:                 mpl_::void_::void_(const mpl_::void_&)                                                                                                     
In file included from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/auxiliary/attr.hpp:18,                                                                                                                       
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/auxiliary.hpp:19,                                                                                                                            
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:15,                                                                                                                                      
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,                                                                                                                                   
                 from main.cpp:2:                                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp: In static member function static void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to_attribute_from_value<Attribute, T, Enable>::call(const T&, Attribute&) [with Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, Enable = void]:                                                                                                                                           
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:99:   instantiated from void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to(const T&, Attribute&) [with T = int, Attribute = mpl_::void_]                 
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:448:   instantiated from static bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::extract_int<T, Radix, 1u, -0x00000000000000001, Accumulator, Accumulate>::parse_main(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, Accumulator = boost::spirit::qi::detail::negative_accumulator<10u>, bool Accumulate = false]                                                      
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:501:   instantiated from static bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::extract_int<T, Radix, 1u, -0x00000000000000001, Accumulator, Accumulate>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, Accumulator = boost::spirit::qi::detail::negative_accumulator<10u>, bool Accumulate = false]                                                           
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/numeric_utils.hpp:106:   instantiated from static bool boost::spirit::qi::extract_int<T, Radix, MinDigits, MaxDigits>::call(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, unsigned int MinDigits = 1u, int MaxDigits = -0x00000000000000001]                                                                                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/int.hpp:98:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<T, Radix, MinDigits, MaxDigits>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = mpl_::void_, T = int, unsigned int Radix = 10u, unsigned int MinDigits = 1u, int MaxDigits = -0x00000000000000001]                                                                                                                            
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/fail_function.hpp:38:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<Iterator, Context, Skipper>::operator()(const Component&, Attribute&) const [with Component = boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, Attribute = mpl_::void_, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >]                                                                                                                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/algorithm/any_if.hpp:171:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::detail::any_if(const First1&, const First2&, const Last&, F&, mpl_::false_) [with Pred = boost::spirit::traits::attribute_not_unused<const boost::fusion::unused_type, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, First1 = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::int_parser_impl<int, 10u, 1u, -0x00000000000000001>, boost::fusion::nil> >, Last = boost::fusion::cons_iterator<const boost::fusion::nil>, First2 = boost::fusion::vector_iterator<boost::fusion::vector1<int&>, 1>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, const boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >]                                                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/algorithm/any_if.hpp:171:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::detail::any_if(const First1&, const First2&, const Last&, F&, mpl_::false_) [with Pred = boost::spirit::traits::attribute_not_unused<const boost::fusion::unused_type, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that the rule you gave it parses into a `string` and an `int`.  The minimum changes I did to get this working was:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

    using namespace boost::spirit;

    int main ()
    {
        std::string input = "asd eee rrr HHH 456";
        std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();
        int result;
        qi::rule<std::string::iterator,int(),qi::space_type> rule =
            (*(qi::char_ - qi::lit("HHH")) >> qi::lit("HHH") >> qi::int_[_val = _1]);
        bool ok = 
            qi::phrase_parse(strbegin, input.end(),
                             rule,
                             qi::space,                  
                             result);                               

        std::cout << ok << std::endl;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
```

Here, constructing a rule object, I specify that I want to output an `int` from this and I also tell it where to assign this value via the semantic action.

Answer (score 5):

The grammar in the initial question can be broken down into having the following attributes:

```cpp
(*(qi::char_ - qi::lit("HHH")) >> qi::lit("HHH") >> qi::int_)
~~~~~~~~~~ string ~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~ unused ~~~    ~~ int ~~
```

If you do not need the results of the `string` attribute, then the [`omit[]`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/omit.html) parsing directive can be used to ignore the attribute of a parser.  For example, the following uses `omit[]` to ignore the `string` attribute above, resulting in a parser that only provides an `int` attribute.

```cpp
(qi::omit[*(qi::char_ - qi::lit("HHH"))] >> qi::lit("HHH") >> qi::int_)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ unused ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~ unused ~~~    ~~ int ~~
```

---

Here is a complete [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0921888a9f3e902e) based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main ()
{
    std::string input = "asd eee rrr HHH 456";
    std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();
    int result;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
            strbegin, input.end(),
            (qi::omit[*(qi::char_ - qi::lit("HHH"))] >> qi::lit("HHH")
              >> qi::int_),
            qi::space,                  
            result);                               

    std::cout << ok << std::endl;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
1
456
```